# puzzled by styles in App.xaml and usercontrol

Tags: wpf, user-controls, app.xaml

Let's say I have three wpf projects in one solution: projectA, ProjectB, and UserControlC.
Now at designtime I can set styles (using the properties sheet) of controls in UsercontrolC to styles defined in the App.xaml of ProjectA, but not App.xaml of projectB. Meanwhile Brushes appear as options but are unable to be selected.

I can repro this behaviour in a brand new solution, without building anything.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Under what circumstances is the UserControl project aware of things defined in another project? Why one project and not the other?

Comment: I am not exactly sure but what I assume is that the `UserControl` pulls the styles from the Starting projects `App.xaml`. So if you have set ProjectA as starting project the UserControl will pull the styles from ProjectA's `App.xaml`

Comment: Thanks for this clue - in fact it seems that the app.xaml of the project that's set as startup *at the time the usercontrol is added* becomes linked to the usercontrol in some way; styles added to that app.xaml later become visible to the usercontrol too. Doesn't seem to be documented. Colours/Brushes don't work properly.

Comment: In fact the Resources don't work properly whatever I do: I can't assign a Brush defined in App.xaml to a background using the designer; I have to hand-code it into the xaml.  Seems to be a win 8.1 issue

Comment: UserControl are not meant for styling or DataTemplate. If you need it then CustomControl is to be used. There is one trick to use styles even in UserControl. You need to create a DP for each control of your UserControl. Then set the styles from app.xaml. I do have a UserControl in which I set the background from app.Xaml